# How do I abort a Jenkins build when the agent disconnects?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

By default, when an agent machine is shut down while in the middle of a build, the build job hangs forever. How do I make the job be automatically aborted or failed instead?

Comment: You could set the build to timeout: https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#top-level-agents